# Microsoft EWS Sending Email with Attachement blocks file afterwards

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm sending an Email with an Attachement (pdf).
This works as intended and without any issues, but afterwards I want to delete that PDF file after its been sent but that does not work because the file is blocked by Windows.

"Access to the path 'C:\IIS_PAGES\wwwroot\FILES\report.pdf' is denied."

I had the same issue with standard .NET SMTP Handler, but after calling dispose() the issue was fixed.
In EWS theres is no dispose or clear method available, how can I fix this issue?

```
                ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("secret", "data", "ad");
             
            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;

            service.Url = new Uri("https://mail.example.com/EWS/exchange.asmx");
            

            EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
            email.ToRecipients.Add(receiver);
            email.Subject = "Test";
            email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(file);        
            email.Body = "test";
            email.Send();
            File.Delete(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add attachment has an overload for using the Stream https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attachmentcollection.addfileattachment?view=exchange-ews-api#microsoft-exchange-webservices-data-attachmentcollection-addfileattachment(system-string-system-io-stream) you should be able to use that and specifically call Dispose on the stream to ensure you not maintaining any handles etc. The EWS managed API is open source so you can see their implementation https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/blob/25a393dbc68b420d25999bdf0a03c23d86412f57/ComplexProperties/AttachmentCollection.cs